# PHP - echo json off url

Tags: php, json, echo

I am trying to echo json of of a url. I can't  figure out how to do it. I have tried many things. Can someone tell me why my code is not functioning properly? No json gets echoed to the screen. Thanks! Here is the link http://www.eastbay.com/shoppingcart/gateway?action=requestKey&_=

```
 <?php
 $raw_json = file_get_contents('http://www.eastbay.com/shoppingcart/gateway?action=requestKey&_=');
 $json_array = json_decode($raw_json, true);
 echo $json_array; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Doesnt appear to be anything returning from that link.

Comment: Oh really? Something returns on my end. Maybe you have to go to eastbay.com first and add something to your shopping cart or something. Thanks!

Comment: does `echo $raw_json` show something?

Comment: Can't echo an array. Try, `print_r($json_array);`

Comment: I think your code isn't working because eastbay.com is working with cookies. Remove your cookies and click the link yourself do you still see the json? if you want to send cookies you should take a look at Curl.

Comment: @PHPhil Yes sir. That is why.

Comment: @PHPhil Any clue how I can take the users current cookies for that site and send a request with them?

Really need help. I'd pay you money if I could get help and get this working.

Comment: Can you show what json you get from that URL, just post it in your question. My second question is what are you trying to do. Do you just want the json you get from your own cookies?

Comment: Yessir, I want the json I get from my own cookies.

This is returned from the url endpoint. As soon as you go to eastbay.com, cookies are set and the json link works.

{"data":{"RequestKey":"0D35kD5D215534FB"},"success":true,"errors":[]}

Comment: Question's language was not clear for the other uesrs.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very pretty, you could put this in a loop but it wil get you started, I hope. Only thing you need to do is change the path where you want to store the cookies, it must be an absolute path.

```
<?php

$cookies = 'C:/folder/folder..../cookies.txt'; //use a absolute path


//Part 1 to get the cookies
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.eastbay.com");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);   // Send Cookies.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);   // Receive Cookies.

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch); 


//part 2 to get the json
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.eastbay.com/shoppingcart/gateway?action=requestKey&_=");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);   // Send Cookies.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);   // Receive Cookies.

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch); 

// Decoding the json in to an array
$decoded = json_decode($output, true);

//using the array to get the data
echo "RequestKey: " . $decoded['data']['RequestKey'] . "<br>";
echo "Success: ". $decoded['success'] . "<br>";

//foreach loop because its an array which hold the errors, it wont output anything because there are no errors.
foreach($decoded['errors'] AS $error){
    echo "Error: " . $error . "<br>";
}

 ?>
```